# Retrieve User LogonTime on Terminal Service with Remote Desktop Services API

Tags: c#, api, remote-desktop, terminal-services

Help me please to examine why code( wrote by FWN in this [topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d0466030-9ac6-42b7-822f-d9f65b9abfac/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts-and-save-results-in-variable?forum=winserverpowershell)) to retrieve User LogonTime on Terminal Service with Remote Desktop Services API does not work properly - each time **wtsinfo.LogonTime** returns different **Int64** value.
Here is the revised code:

**RDPInfo.cs :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RDP
{
    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
    {
        WTSInitialProgram,
        WTSApplicationName,
        WTSWorkingDirectory,
        WTSOEMId,
        WTSSessionId,
        WTSUserName,
        WTSWinStationName,
        WTSDomainName,
        WTSConnectState,
        WTSClientBuildNumber,
        WTSClientName,
        WTSClientDirectory,
        WTSClientProductId,
        WTSClientHardwareId,
        WTSClientAddress,
        WTSClientDisplay,
        WTSSessionInfo,
        WTSClientProtocolType,
    }

    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit,
    }

    public class RDPInfo
    {
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public Int32 SessionID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pWinStationName;
            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct WTSINFO 
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
            public Int64 LogonTime;
        }

        public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
        {
            IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
            return server;
        }

        public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
        {
            WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
        }

        public static List<RDPSession> ListUsers(String ServerName)
        {
            List<RDPSession> List = new List<RDPSession>();
            WTSINFO wtsinfo = new WTSINFO();

            IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
            serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

            IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientNamePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr wtsinfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientDisplayPtr = IntPtr.Zero;


            try
            {

                Int32 sessionCount = 0;
                Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
                Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
                uint bytes = 0;
                if (retVal != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
                    {
                        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                        currentSession += dataSize;

                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);
                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName, out clientNamePtr, out bytes);
                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSSessionInfo, out wtsinfoPtr, out bytes);

                        RDPSession temp = new RDPSession();
                        temp.Client = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr);
                        temp.Server = ServerName;
                        temp.UserName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr);
                        temp.Domain = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr);
                        temp.ConnectionState = si.State;
                        temp.SessionId = si.SessionID;

                        //WTSINFO dt = (WTSINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTSINFO));
                        //DateTime date = new DateTime(dt.LogonTime);
                        //temp.sessionInfo = date;

                        wtsinfo = (WTSINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(wtsinfoPtr, typeof(WTSINFO));
                        temp.sessionInfo = wtsinfo.LogonTime;

                        List.Add(temp);

                        WTSFreeMemory(clientNamePtr);
                        WTSFreeMemory(userPtr);
                        WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
                        WTSFreeMemory(wtsinfoPtr);
                    }
                    WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.Release(SessionInfoPtr);
                Marshal.Release(userPtr);
                Marshal.Release(domainPtr);
                Marshal.Release(clientNamePtr);
                //Marshal.Release(wtsinfoPtr);
                CloseServer(serverHandle);
            }

            return List;
        }
    }



    public class RDPSession
    {
        public string UserName;
        public string Domain;
        public int SessionId;
        public string Client;
        public string Server;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS ConnectionState;
        //public RDP.RDPInfo.WTSINFO sessionInfo;
        public Int64 sessionInfo;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RDP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<RDPSession> ServerList = new List<RDPSession>();
            ServerList = RDPInfo.ListUsers("SERVERNAME");
            foreach (RDPSession item in ServerList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-35} {3,-40}", item.UserName, item.ConnectionState, item.Client, item.sessionInfo);
            }
        }
```

P.S. As I think I need to get LogonTime from WTSINFO in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736370(v=vs.85).aspx)

P.S.S. I have added [WTSINFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736370(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  from [WTS_INFO_CLASS enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861(v=vs.85).aspx). [WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) get right answer. But [WTSINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736370(v=vs.85).aspx) returns each time different **Int64** value. Could you help me with that? How to convert that to **DateTime**? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you don't find someone willing to debug your code.

Comment: Maybe, but it's not my code and I don't deeply understand how it works. This is updated version of  `QuerySessionInformation.ps1`
`Written by Ryan Ries, Jan. 2013, with help from MSDN and Stackoverflow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by [Chris Lewis [MSFT]](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/chris%20lewis%20%5Bmsft%5D/?ws=usercard-mini) in this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cbfd802c-5add-49f3-b020-c901f1a8d3f4/retrieve-user-logontime-on-terminal-service-with-remote-desktop-services-api?forum=csharpgeneral).
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace WTSInfoExample
{

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS:int
    {
        WTSInitialProgram = 0,
        WTSApplicationName = 1,
        WTSWorkingDirectory = 2,
        WTSOEMId = 3,
        WTSSessionId = 4,
        WTSUserName = 5,
        WTSWinStationName = 6,
        WTSDomainName = 7,
        WTSConnectState = 8,
        WTSClientBuildNumber = 9,
        WTSClientName = 10,
        WTSClientDirectory = 11,
        WTSClientProductId = 12,
        WTSClientHardwareId = 13,
        WTSClientAddress = 14,
        WTSClientDisplay = 15,
        WTSClientProtocolType = 16,
        WTSIdleTime = 17,
        WTSLogonTime = 18,
        WTSIncomingBytes = 19,
        WTSOutgoingBytes = 20,
        WTSIncomingFrames = 21,
        WTSOutgoingFrames = 22,
        WTSClientInfo = 23,
        WTSSessionInfo = 24,
        WTSSessionInfoEx = 25,
        WTSConfigInfo = 26,
        WTSValidationInfo = 27,
        WTSSessionAddressV4 = 28,
        WTSIsRemoteSession = 29
    }


    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS:int
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit,
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct WTSINFOA
    {
        public const int WINSTATIONNAME_LENGTH = 32;
        public const int DOMAIN_LENGTH = 17;
        public const int USERNAME_LENGTH = 20;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        public int SessionId;
        public int IncomingBytes;
        public int OutgoingBytes;
        public int IncomingFrames;
        public int OutgoingFrames;
        public int IncomingCompressedBytes;
        public int OutgoingCompressedBytes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = WINSTATIONNAME_LENGTH)]
        public byte[] WinStationNameRaw;
        public string WinStationName
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(WinStationNameRaw);
            }
        }
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = DOMAIN_LENGTH)]
        public byte[] DomainRaw;
        public string Domain
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(DomainRaw);
            }
        }
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = USERNAME_LENGTH + 1)]
        public byte[] UserNameRaw;
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(UserNameRaw);
            }
        }
        public long ConnectTimeUTC;
        public DateTime ConnectTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(ConnectTimeUTC);
            }
        }
        public long DisconnectTimeUTC;
        public DateTime DisconnectTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(DisconnectTimeUTC);
            }
        }
        public long LastInputTimeUTC;
        public DateTime LastInputTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(LastInputTimeUTC);
            }
        }
        public long LogonTimeUTC;
        public DateTime LogonTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(LogonTimeUTC);
            }
        }
        public long CurrentTimeUTC;
        public DateTime CurrentTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(CurrentTimeUTC);
            }
        }
    }
    public class RDPInfo
    {
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public Int32 SessionID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public String pWinStationName;
            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
        }

        public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
        {
            IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
            return server;
        }

        public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
        {
            WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
        }

        public static List<RDPSession> ListUsers(String ServerName)
        {
            List<RDPSession> List = new List<RDPSession>();

            IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
            serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

            IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientNamePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr wtsinfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientDisplayPtr = IntPtr.Zero;


            try
            {

                Int32 sessionCount = 0;
                Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
                Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
                uint bytes = 0;
                if (retVal != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
                    {
                        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                        currentSession += dataSize;

                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName, out clientNamePtr, out bytes);
                        WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSSessionInfo, out wtsinfoPtr, out bytes);

                        var wtsinfo = (WTSINFOA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(wtsinfoPtr, typeof(WTSINFOA));
                        RDPSession temp = new RDPSession();
                        temp.Client = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr);
                        temp.Server = ServerName;
                        temp.UserName = wtsinfo.UserName;
                        temp.Domain = wtsinfo.Domain;
                        temp.ConnectionState = si.State;
                        temp.SessionId = si.SessionID;
                        temp.sessionInfo = wtsinfo;
                        List.Add(temp);

                        WTSFreeMemory(clientNamePtr);
                        WTSFreeMemory(wtsinfoPtr);
                    }
                    WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServer(serverHandle);
            }

            return List;
        }
    }

    public class RDPSession
    {
        public string UserName;
        public string Domain;
        public int SessionId;
        public string Client;
        public string Server;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS ConnectionState;
        public WTSINFOA sessionInfo;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<RDPSession> ServerList = new List<RDPSession>();
            ServerList = RDPInfo.ListUsers("SERVERNAME");
            foreach (RDPSession item in ServerList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,-15} {2,-35} {3,-40}", item.UserName, item.ConnectionState, item.Client, item.sessionInfo.LogonTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```